# Gallery image counter in jQuery swipebox plugin

Tags: jquery

I'm building a custom image/video gallery with Swipebox plugin, but I only need a image/video counter and the existing Swipebox script doesn't provide that.

I would like the image/video counter to be combined with the PREV button that you can see when hovering that I already have working.

I don't have a fiddle, because I have more css's and scripts separated made and don't know if it will work like that in fiddle.

[Here is the link](http://newband.nl/gallery/index.html) and ignore the big thumbnails in the beginning that is for testing everything works only I don't have a counter script.

Can anyone help me with that must be very easy.

From the jquery.swipebox.js script you can see where the counter should go:

```
<footer id="swipebox-bottom-bar">\
  <ul>\
    <li><a href="#" id="swipebox-prev" class="prev"><span>1/5</span></a>
    </li>\
    <li><a href="#" id="swipebox-next">Next</a>
    </li>\
  </ul>\
</footer>\
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the easiest way was to just make the changes directly in the plugin code since all the information you need is already there.

**What I did was**

Changed the HTML template to add new IDs for the counter. These IDs will be used as holders.

```
<footer id="swipebox-bottom-bar">\
  <ul>\
    <li>
       <a href="#" id="swipebox-prev" class="prev">
         <span>
           <span id="swipebox-current-slide"></span>/
           <span id="swipebox-all-slides"></span>
         </span>
      </a>
    </li>\
    <li><a href="#" id="swipebox-next">Next</a></li>\
  </ul>\
</footer>\
```

In the *build* function inside the method add the following line to show the total slide number

```
$('#swipebox-all-slides').text(elements.length);
```

Note: Add it after the `html` is appended to the body

In the *setSlide* function inside the method add the following line to change the active slide number

```
$('#swipebox-current-slide').text(index + 1);
```

You can add it after the line where the *disabled* class from the prev/next buttons is removed.

---

[**You can test it here**](http://jsfiddle.net/fhaovr0v/1/) (links in the fiddle are external; they will brake when the page changes)

Comment: Thanks mate! It works in the fiddle going test it in my code. Really appreciate it!